# Добавление элементов в ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать динамический ListView, в который, при нажатии на кнопку, будут добавляться элементы. Посмотрел, как это делается, но, к сожалению, ни один из вариантов не заработал - при нажатии просто ничего не происходит. Вот что есть:

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> listItems;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button bttAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttAdd);
    bttAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;
            listItems.add("Редактировать " + count);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще такой подход должен работать для кастомных адаптеров. Так что несрабатывание в сём случае, похоже, суть особенность реализации системного адаптера, коя предполагает добавление данных через сам адаптер, а не через список, переданный в конструктор. Вот код с [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125428/3212712) (замените им последние две строки в слушателе нажатий):

```
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
adapter.add("Редактировать " + count);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.